# SQL Server Replication - commands waiting in distribution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, replication

Our infrastructure is as follows:

Publisher on Live db server, Distibutor and subscriber on our mirror server.

Basically yesterday we were doing archiving on a huge table on our live server, (tblEventlog), and I was deleting rows month by time, millions of records. 
This caused the transaction log to fill up completely...so when we restarted server and got the space back, we now have 144225820 commands in our distribution database (on mirror)...and estimated time of 27 hours to apply and catch up.

Basically I am looking for the quickest fix to this - I know the offending table is tblEventLog. Can we drop this from the mirror and then export a copy (with the deletes applied) from Live...would this have any effect on the transactions waiting in the distribution db? Would the distributor still try and apply them even though the rows are now gone?

If so, whats the best way out of this?

Publisher is SQL Server 2008, Subscriber server is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: apologies, have updated.

Comment: It's probable that "finishing" the replication takes much more time than simply recreating the whole subscriptionand initializing it from a snapshot. This would incur some downtime on the distributor while the tables are truncated and re-filled, though. If the existing tables are already huge, a possibly faster way is to restore a backup, then [initialize replication from that backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-from-a-backup).

Comment: As an aside, it tends to pay off to put "huge" tables like this in their own publications, so you don't lose/desync everything else if the subscriptions for them ever need reinitializing. Of course, this assumes the table can change on its own with no concern for transaction ordering in other publications, but that's usually the case for flat log tables.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. The database is 500gb, so reinitialising is last resort... So if I pause replication by stopping the sql server agent, drop that table and export a fresh from live, then restart the sql agent, that will have no effect on the commands waiting in the distribution database?

Comment: It almost certainly will cause trouble. I've never been in the position that I could fix up these things *without* reinitializing the subscription. I suspect it can be done, but not without a lot of heartache and groveling around in the internals, and ultimately ending up reinitializing anyway. I agree with the existing close vote that if you want to go down that road, you're more likely to get answers from dba.SE.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen...looks like we might have to go down the reinitialise route! What happens to the commands waiting in the distribution database whenever the relevant subscription is removed? Are they deleted?

Comment: @Ricky: it depends on a couple of things (immediate_sync and allow_anonymous spring to mind). Why? If you were able to restore your subscriber to a point in time where those commands could be relevant, the distribution agent could pick up where it left off. Either way, they should for sure be gone once the distributor retention period elapses.